# What's new in Linq to SQL in .NET 4.0

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

Does anyone know if there is anything new in LINQ to SQL in the 4.0 Framework? I know they said LINQ to SQL was not going to be supported anymore in favor of pushing the Entity Framework, but maybe they added new features or fixed some bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damien Guard compiled a comprehensive [list of changes to LINQ to SQL in .NET 4](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40).

Most changes are minor, but there were various improvements made, especially in performance and stability.

Comment: Thanks. I guess they didn't add an overall setting to turn off optimistic concurrency